# Why isn't my arc line width clearing?

Tags: canvas

am trying to draw two shapes on a canvas. The first, is a half circle. the second is a line.

Half Circle:

```
this.ctx.beginPath();
this.ctx.arc(cs, cs, radius, angle, angle+Math.PI, true);
this.ctx.fillStyle = '#FC4F54';
this.ctx.fill();
this.ctx.stroke();
this.ctx.closePath();
```

Line:

```
var x = (Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2) * this.canvasSize) + cs;
var y = (Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2) * this.canvasSize) + cs;

this.ctx.beginPath();
this.ctx.moveTo(cs,cs);
this.ctx.lineTo(x,y);
this.ctx.lineWidth = 2 * radius;
this.ctx.strokeStyle = "#ffffff[![enter image description here][1]][1]";
this.ctx.stroke();
this.ctx.closePath();
```

When I run them in the order shown above I get this result:

[image]

But when I change the Order of the two around so the line is first, this is the result:

[image]

If I increase the radius of the arc, for the second, i start to see the red color at the center. Which makes me think that somehow the lineWidth from the line is crossing over into the arc style. However, if I try to explicitly set the lineWidth for the circle to zero, it has no effect.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearance of the arc is caused by the change to the lineWidth as you suspected.

When you attempted to set the lineWidth to 0 this had no effect because a value of zero is ignored, as stated [in this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineWidth).

If you set the lineWidth to 1 before drawing the arc then you will get the same result whichever order you draw the arc and the line in.

Comment: In my particular case I don't want the line to appear so I set it to 0.1. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Corndog, if you don't want the line, just don't call stroke().